# Что нравится детям в рассказах Льва Толстого?

Tags: литература

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ к ВОПРОСУ

Скоро С. исполнится 6 лет, но он всё ещё не любит читать. Поэтому я изумился, когда застал С. за чтением сборника рассказов Льва Толстого, которые адресованы детям.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Спасибо всем, кто помог мне понять поведение С.

Comment: Молодец Ваш С.! Сколько детей, которым 10-15-..., а они "все еще не любят читать"...

Comment: Помню эти рассказы с детского сада : *Филипок, Лев и собачка, Косточка*...  
"Все засмеялись, а Ваня заплакал"

Answer (score 2):

Толстой писал детские книжки удивительно детским языком, понятным и простым. Я помню свое восприятие его произведений - там само построение предложений какое-то детское. Ну и, конечно, стилистика русской народной сказки тоже присутствует, с повторами, с интригой. Мне кажется, для ребенка 6 лет это тот самый необходимый и достаточный уровень, который может привить интерес к чтению.

Comment: Л. Толстой - это классика, но он, на мой взгляд,  уже кажется теперь устаревшим, так не говорят  современные дети, а вот А. Гайдар, С. Маршак и др. современные детские писатели - они должны помочь детям придти к большой литературе. Но нужна помощь взрослых: показать, обратить внимание, поднести ребёнку нужный текст, может, для начала почитать вместе с ним. Это зависит от конкретной личности ребёнка